# Checking whether a string contains any numeric values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table:

```
create table students
(
    stuName varchar2(100),
    cgpa number
);
```

My goal is to create a PL/SQL trigger that would fire if anyone tries to enter a name that contains any numeric values. My attempt:

```
create or replace trigger invalid_name
before insert
on students
for each row
declare
    vName varchar2(100);
begin
    vName := :new.stuName;
    if upper(vName) like upper(vName) then
        vName := initcap(vName);
    end if;
exception
    when value_error then
        dbms_output.put_line('ERROR: Name contains numeric value(s).');
end;
```

I thought if the `upper` function were to act on a string containing any numeric value in it, it would throw an exception. But that's not happening and `insert` action is being executed.

Comment: No, `upper` will not modify characters in the string that are not lowercase characters.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using a constraint rather than a trigger.

```
create table foo (
    name varchar2(100) NOT NULL
    constraint name_non_numeric check ( not regexp_like( name, '[0-9]' ) )
);

Table created.

insert into foo ( name ) values ( 'Andy' );

1 row created.

> insert into foo ( name ) values ( 'Logan 5' );

insert into foo ( name ) values ( 'Logan 5' )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (NAMESPACE.NAME_NON_NUMERIC) violated
```

Comment: Constraints are definitely better than triggers for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to replace, but check and raise an error, you can use [this trick](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php) and raise an error if the result is not null:

```
SELECT LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE('123b', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) FROM dual;
Result: 1

SELECT LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE('a123b', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) FROM dual;
Result: 2

SELECT LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE('1256.54', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) FROM dual;
Result: null

SELECT LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE ('-56', ' +-.0123456789',' '))) FROM dual;
Result: null
```